# Angular: Function expressions are not supported in decorators

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a legacy code I didn't fully understand so far but have to maintenance, lol))

The code was written components as I described below, and it works with `ng serve`, but crashes with `ng build --prod`.

The problem with `providers` field:

```
@Component({
  selector: "legacy-component",
  templateUrl: './legacy-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./legacy-component.scss'],
  //Take a look at "providers", the problem is there
  providers: [provideWidget(LegacyComponent, {
    id: "legacy",
    options: {},
    layout: { minCols: 2, cols: 4, rows: 2 },
    info: {
      name: "Legacy Compoent",
      image: "assets/img/legacy/legacy.png",
      description: ""
    }
  })]
})
export class LegacyComponent {...}
```

I don't really understand what's going on here with providers, but when I try to build the project I have:

```
Error during template compile of 'LegacyComponent'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'provideWidget'
    'provideWidget' contains the error at some/path/other-class.ts
      Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

But if I'll rewrite `provideWidget` as a function, I'll have different error:

```
Error during template compile of 'LegacyComponent'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'provideWidget' was called.
```

*I assuming* that it's probably wasn't a great idea to have a function call in providers, but I supposed to launch the code and **I just can't replace** `provideWidget` call with some static data due to complex logic of that function.

Does anyone to how to build production version in that case?

Comment: I mean you can't have functions in decorators since they are just compile time wrappers. You could do useFactory and provide a static function or useClass and provide a class

Answer (score -1):

[Reference to provider type](https://angular.io/api/core/Provider)

Here you can see that Provider can be `TypeProvider | ValueProvider | ClassProvider | ConstructorProvider | ExistingProvider | FactoryProvider`.

So if you want a dynamic provider you need to use `FactoryProvider`:

```
{ provide: 'SomeToken', useFactory: factoryFunction }
```

Another way if provideWidget is stateless function, you can create a constant before class definition and assign it to a const value and use as `ValueProvider`.